# Error installing Ruby in Yosemite

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-yosemite

I have recently updated my OS X to 10.10 and since then facing issue installing ruby through RVM. There is a dependency on gcc46 which I am unable to resolve. Any help is appreciated. Below is the error stack.

```
rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p547
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #removing src/ruby-1.9.3-p547 - please wait
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #removing rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547 - please wait
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p547.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system - please wait
Installing required packages: gcc46 - please wait
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install gcc46',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/saurabh/.rvm/log/1414321731_ruby-1.9.3-p547/package_install_gcc46.log
+rvm_pretty_print:10> case stdout (stdout)
+rvm_pretty_print:11> [[ -t 1 ]]
+rvm_pretty_print:11> return 1
+rvm_warn:4> printf %b 'There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation\n'
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation
+requirements_osx_brew_libs_install:11> case 10.10 (10.6)
+requirements_osx_brew_libs_install:18> return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.

brew install gcc46                
==> Installing gcc46 from homebrew/homebrew-versions
gcc46: OS X Mavericks or older is required for stable.
Use `brew install devel or --HEAD` for newer.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

**EDIT :**

I was able to install using below command.

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Could someone help me understand what's the difference with the above command? Thanks

Comment: RVM expected you've got installed gcc4.6, but it seems to there is some old unsupported receipt version in your current receipt brew list.. try to brew update, brew upgrade, brew doctor... And the difference is, in your last command you use for compiling ruby clang (default c compiler on darwin)...

Comment: I have tried brew update. It did not solve the issue. I am thinking there is no suppported gcc46 for OSX 10.10 as yet. I am not sure though.

Comment: I was able to install gcc48 on Yosemitte by: brew install homebrew/versions/gcc48

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @JanStrnádek for the answer. I solved all the dependencies from left to right and installed gcc using the below command and tried installing ruby again. It worked.

```
brew install homebrew/versions/gcc48
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use the latest version whenever possible, or else check the correct versions of each component which is compatible with the version of the component you are installing.

If you follow [this guide](http://installrails.com/steps/choose_os_version) it will be much easier.

I am completely new to ruby, but it worked fine for me by using this.