# How to recover from failed Ruby version update?

Tags: ruby

On attempting to update Ruby version I get a failure with some dependencies. The output of which is copied below. I need to correct this situation or perform a time machine restore (ideally without rolling back my entire system).

What would be the best way to recover from this situation?

```
Pauls-MacBook-Pro:~ pauldriver$ cd Sites/base/sites/all/themes/primal/
ruby-1.9.3-p551 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p551'
Pauls-MacBook-Pro:primal pauldriver$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p547 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

Pauls-MacBook-Pro:primal pauldriver$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p551
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p551.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on         binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system.....
Installing required packages: gcc48.....
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install gcc48',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/pauldriver/.rvm/log/1417181615_ruby-1.9.3-        p551/package_install_gcc48.log
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 1 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation\n'
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation
++ case "$_system_version" in
++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
Pauls-MacBook-Pro:primal pauldriver$
```

Comment: did you Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable. ?

Comment: Thank you and yes I did. brew tap --repair was throwing all kinds of stuff back at me regrading compatibility with php. Well over my head frankly. I did arrive at a solution though and will an answer my own question below. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my problem was connected with gcc48 and some confusion with an earlier version.

I eventually found a solution via the following stackoverflow post  [Error installing Ruby in Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572412/error-installing-ruby-in-yosemite)